# bash script: using "script" command to write console output to a file in real time

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to capture console output and write it to a file in realtime. For that, I am using "script" command with "-f" option, which flushes output after each write. However, that doesn't give me the output file in "real-time". It seems the command doesn't write to the output file very often. 
So my question are how often does it write ? and how to make it writes more often ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try `screen` with its logging feature plus `logfile flush seconds` (untested).

Answer (score 0):

If it's bash, adding the following to my .bash_profile works for me to make the bash history update in realtime:

```
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Admittedly this is a work around, and doesn't answer your question regarding the script command ...